# What would cause an array-cast column to save as "0"?

Tags: laravel, httprequest, paypal-ipn

I have a Paypal IPN listener logging incoming data. For some reason, I'm seeing just a string `0` saved in a column, `data`, where JSON strings are supposed to be saved.

Any idea what kind of raw post data might be translating into a string `0`? In the meaning, I'm updating the listener to saw the raw post body to see what's up. Paypal's IPN history page shows that it's sending valid data.

Eloquent:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array'
];
```

MySQL:

```
data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
```

Post request to listener:

```
Header: content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: ? (supposed to be an url-encoded string)
```

Comment: Is there any [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) defined for it?

Comment: @Mozammil No mutator, just the casting in Laravel.

Comment: post the json string you are trying to save or casting.